# Does installing KDE also install sddm?

Tags: desktop-environment, kde5, sddm

I have a machine running Linux Mint 17.3 with XFCE which I have just upgraded to 18.

I have also decided to give KDE Plasma a try so I followed [this guide](https://www.google.it/amp/www.tecmint.com/install-kde-plasma-5-in-linux/amp/) to install it. However, I wasn't prompted to choose between lightdm and sddm during installation.

Is installing KDE also supposed to install and enable sddm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, I was missing the `sddm` package on this system. Installing it allowed to immediately choose sddm as my display manager:

```
sudo apt-get install sddm
```